# Accessing PFObject Subclassed Properties from a Query

Tags: parse-platform, properties

I am using Parse and have created a subclass of PFObject.  When creating objects it makes things much easier.  Once objects are created, I am experimenting with querying the database and accessing the custom properties I created.  What I am finding is that I cannot use dot notation to access the properties when I am working the the PFObjects returned from the query.  Is this normal?

Here is subclass I created.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class MessagePFObject: PFObject
{
    @NSManaged var messageSender : String
    @NSManaged var messageReceiver : String
    @NSManaged var messageMessage : String
    @NSManaged var messageSeen : Bool
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // Custom Query method.
    override class func query() -> PFQuery?
    {
        let query = PFQuery(className: MessagePFObject.parseClassName())
        query.includeKey("user")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        return query
    }

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    init(messageSenderInput: String?, messageReceiverInput: String?, messageMessageInput: String?)
    {

        super.init()

        self.messageSender = messageSenderInput!
        self.messageReceiver = messageReceiverInput!
        self.messageMessage = messageMessageInput!
        self.messageSeen = false     
    }

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }
}

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ EXTENSION +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

extension MessagePFObject : PFSubclassing
{
    class func parseClassName() -> String
    {
        return "MessagePFObject"
    }

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    override class func initialize()
    {
        var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my query and what I am required to do to access the properties.  createdAt, updatedAt, etc are all available with dot notation but none of my custom properties are.  You can see I access messageSeen with element.objectForKey("messageSeen").

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "messageSender == %@ OR messageReceiver == %@", self.currentUser!.username!, self.currentUser!.username!)
        let query = messagePFObject.queryWithPredicate(predicate)
        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil && objects!.count > 0
            {
                for element in objects!
                {
                    print(element)
                    print(element.parseClassName)
                    print(element.objectId)
                    print(element.createdAt)
                    print(element.updatedAt)
                    print(element.objectForKey("messageSeen"))
                }
            }
            else if error != nil
            {
                print(error)
            }
        })
```

If this is normal then that is fine.  I just want to make sure I am not missing something.

Take care,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Your object subclass has to implement the `PFSubclassing` protocol and you need to call `MessagePFObject.registerSubclass()` in your app delegate.

The parse documentation is very good : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses